# Tooltips disappears with Bootstrap 3 in Joomla 3.2.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, joomla3.0

I'm use Joomla 3.2.2 and in my Template Bootstrap 3.1.1. If I go with the mouse over a tooltip, then disappears this. This occurs, for example, in the registration form. With Joomla 3.2.1, this has worked. Does anyone know of this problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: I know core Joomla uses Bootstrap 2.1, perhaps the two different versions are conflicting.  Have you checked your browser console for any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, with the following css code I could solve the problem temporarily. Write this code in your own template.

```
label
{
    display : inline !important;
}
```

The problem is that is in a hover over the label in the following code...

```
display : none;
```

Is this a Bug of Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla released version 3.2.3 today and or looks like the tooltip bug was in the list of bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Bootstrap 3 and not Joomla 3.2.x

To prove this I removed the script code loading Bootstrap from my site and the tooltip remains (along with the labels).

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but actually, the problem is with Mootools. If you realized, this happens only if you have Joomla's Mootools loaded on the page(s) where the tooltip elements are disappearing. The fix is simple:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.hasTooltip').each(function(){this.show = null; this.hide = null;});
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Also add

```
.hasTooltip {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

to your template's css file.

Comment: Actually, I am sure it does. Question was "why tooltips dissapear on hover". They all have this class (.hasTooltip) and not all of them are labels. Original question was also about input fields in registration, read it.